# Best way to approximate function

Tags: functions, approximation

What is the best approximation for function like on attached image ? Function is increasing or decreasing from "spike" to "spike"

**Zoom to the first few members:**
[image: Zoom to the start of function]

**All members:**
[image: Whole function]

Comment: I think, you can try [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) over $\sin$ and $\cos$. Although the zoomed image doesn't seem that periodic, the overall picture may fit well in average.

Comment: maybe you can use piecewise polynomials (I guess, 2nd or 3rd grade can be successful)

Answer (score 1):

I would be skeptical of the validity of the wiggles.  I would make it a straight line from the max to the min, set the min to zero and the max to $260000$  Then all you need to remember is the $x$ positions of the maxima and minima.  Then I would plot the number of the minimum against its $x$ position and see if I could find a smooth curve for them, same for the max.

Comment: `Then I would plot the number of the minimum against its x position and see if I could find a smooth curve for them` - I quite dont undestand it :( Why plot min/max values separatly ?

Comment: @MartinPerry:  I am trying to find $f(n)=$ position of the nth minimum and $g(n)=$ position of nth maximum.  It looks like they may be of the form an+bsin cn, where the sine term causes the shift in frequency.